# Romans 6:5, is it mentioned "in the likeness of his resurrection" in Greek manuscripts?

Tags: romans

I looked Romans 6:5, I found "in the likeness of his resurrection" in: KJV, NKJV, ASV, ESV, in ESV "in a resurrection like his".

GNB has different translation.

In all Arabic translations I didn't find a phrase equals "in the likeness" with "resurrection"

Is it mentioned "in the likeness" with "resurrection" in original Greek manuscripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No, the original Geek does not have the second "in the likeness" or even "his".

Whenever you see italicized words in the KJV, that means those words are not in the original manuscript. The translators wanted readers to know those words were added to provide clarification of reading.

I have bolded and italicized the added words:

> "For if we have been planted together in the likeness of his death, we
>   shall be also ***in the likeness*** of ***his*** resurrection:" (Romans 6:5
>   KJV, emphasis added)

### The Greek

ει γαρ συμφυτοι γεγοναμεν τω ομοιωματι του θανατου αυτου αλλα και της αναστασεως εσομεθα

rawly translated

> If for together-planted we-have-become to-the likeness of-the death
>   of-him but also of-the up-standing we-shall-be

ει(if) γαρ(for) συμφυτοι(together-planted) γεγοναμεν(we-have-become) τω(to-the) ομοιωματι(likeness) του(of-the) θανατου(death) αυτουof-him) αλλα(but) και(also) της(of-the αναστασεως(up-standing) εσομεθα(we-shall-be)

### Resurrection (up-standing)

The term "up-standing" "αναστασεως" is always translated as **Resurrection**

---

- Raw translation from **Interlinear Scripture Analyzer 3** software.

Comment: If understand this more straightforward reading: *If we are united in baptism with the likeness of his death we will be people of the resurrected.*

Answer (score 1):

Here I'll put the Greek with each word being numbered and my translation below to show which words connect to the English I put it into.

> BYZ  Romans 6:5 Εἰ 1 γὰρ 2 σύμφυτοι 3 γεγόναμεν 4 τῷ 5 ὁμοιώματι 6 τοῦ 7 θανάτου 8 αὐτοῦ 9, ἀλλὰ 10 καὶ 11 τῆς 12 ἀναστάσεως 13 ἐσόμεθα· 14

My translation would come out to
"For 2 if 1 [we] 4 become 4 identified 3 with 3 Him 9 [in] 8 the 5 likenes 6 [of] 8 His 9 death 8 we 14 also 10,11 [will be] 14 [of] 13 the 12 resurrection. 13"

[words] are not direct Greek words but come from the Greek word cited. English tends to have more words and fewer conjugations so they must be put in to have it make sense in English.

I hope that illustrates that the likeness connects to his death but is also implied by being tied to the resurrection. The genitive case for 'of the resurrection' brings along the same idea and whether you leave it implied in your translation or just repeat it depends on the language and style of translation.